# Funcionamento da função scanf()

Tags: c, c++

Alguém pode me explicar como é o funcionamento da função scanf()? Não o básico, mas como funciona o mecanismo que ela possui de retornar o número de argumentos que foram lidos. Para quem retorna? Por que retorna?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ela retorna o número de atribuições efectuadas para facilitar o tratamento de erros.

Imagina que deves ler uma data (formato yyyy-mm-dd), um valor de temperatura e, facultativamente, um valor de pluviosidade. Por exemplo

```
2019-01-01 24.3 0
2019-01-02 24.6
2019-01-03 #na
2019-01-04 25 1.1
```

Com `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); sscanf(buf, "%d-%d-%d%lf%lf", &y, &m, &d, &t, &p);` os valores devolvidos serão

```
5 para a primeira linha: tudo ok
4 para a segunda linha; falta pluviosidade
3 para terceira linha; falta temperatura e pluviosidade
5 para quarta linha
```

Answer (score 0):

Não vou explicar muito, vou mostrar uma coisa que as pessoas têm muita dificuldade em C: leitura do teclado.

O programa abaixo faz a leitura de 2 números inteiros por linha.
O programa só vai aceitar exatamente a digitação de 2 números por linha, em sequência (mas com espaços entre eles). Se tiver coisas que não são números vai acusar erro, e se tiver mais de 2 campos vai acusar erro, mesmo que os campos adicionais sejam numéricos.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int n_read, x, y;
  char buf[100], tmp[100];

  for (;;)
  {
    printf("*\n");
    printf("* digite 2 numeros inteiros: ");

    // le uma linha completa, sem interpretar os dados
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

    // faz a leitura, mas aproveitando a linha digitada
    n_read = sscanf(buf, "%d%d%s", &x, &y, tmp);
    printf("* foram lidos %d campos\n", n_read);

    if (n_read < 2)
    {
      printf("* erro na leitura, faltando numeros\n");
      continue;
    }

    if (n_read > 2)
    {
      printf("* erro, campos adicionais no restante da linha\n");
      continue;
    }

    printf("* ok, leitura bem sucedida, x=%d e y=%d\n", x, y);
  }
}
```